# Using threads causes a weird bug where some points aren't getting colored.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sfml

I'm adding code as reference but you probably don't need to understand mandlerbot to help me with this weird multi-threading side effect.

I'm generating a simple Mandelbrot using this code:

```html
void compute_mandelbrot(double left, double right, double top, double bottom, double start, double end)
{

 int r = 0x00, g = 0x00, b = 0x00;
 for (int y = start; y < end; ++y)
 {
  for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
  {
   // Work out the point in the complex plane that
   // corresponds to this pixel in the output image.
   complex<double> c(left + (x * (right - left) / WIDTH),
    top + (y * (bottom - top) / HIGHT));

   // Start off z at (0, 0).
   complex<double> z(0.0, 0.0);

   // Iterate z = z^2 + c until z moves more than 2 units
   // away from (0, 0), or we've iterated too many times.
   int iterations = 0;
   while (abs(z) < 2.0 && iterations < MAX_ITERATIONS)
   {
    z = (z * z) + c;

    ++iterations;
   }

   if (r <= MAX_ITERATIONS)
    r = iterations;

   unsigned int colour = r | (r << 8) | (r << 16);

   vertex.color = sf::Color(r, g, b, 255);
   //vertex.color = sf::Color(6525, 1111, 222, 255);
   vertex.position = sf::Vector2f(x, y);
   mutex.lock();
   varray.append(vertex);
   mutex.unlock();

  }
 }
}
```

which works just fine. But when I try to use threads to speed up the process I get an unusual result

```html
void slicer(double left, double right, double top, double bottom, int slices)
{
 int sliceSize = 800 / slices;
 double start = 0, end = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < slices; i++)
 {
  start = i * sliceSize;
  end = ((1 + i) * sliceSize);

  thrd.push_back(thread(compute_mandelbrot, left, right, top, bottom, start, end));

 }

 for (int i = 0; i < slices; i++)
 {
  thrd[i].join();
 }
 thrd.clear();

}
```

result: [image]

Now the weird part that is hurting my head, if I send a single slice like this

compute_mandelbrot(left, right, top, bottom, 400, 480);

without threads then it works fine, which is why it's so hard for me to understand why when I have threads render each slice separately there appear to be a lot of uncoloured bits all over the place.

Even more weird is that the unrendered parts are random each time, except for a single slice in the middle (see picture) that never has any missing colour if slices = 4

Comment: Seems like a simple race condition. What is varray? Seems like you have one vector that you append to from multiple threads. The mutex prevents the appends from corrupting the container, but does nothing to ensure that the order of appends makes sense. (clarification: I don't know sfml).

Comment: @Frax varray is a vertex array (sf::VertexArray varray(sf::Points);)

Comment: @Frax Any idea how I could ensure the order? Or what I should be doing to ensure it?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Frax `sf::VertexArray` is basically a `std::vector<sf::Vertex>` with some added logic for drawing.

Comment: @reversecodingguru Reserve the total amount of elements for the vector (which you should do anyway to prevent memory fragmentation and reallocation) and then access vertices by index rather than appending them.

Comment: @Mario I wish I understood that, haha. Can you put it in layman's terms for a novice such as myself

Comment: Call `reserve` with the right amount of capacity at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I moved

```html
   unsigned int colour = r | (r << 8) | (r << 16);

   vertex.color = sf::Color(r, g, b, 255);
   vertex.position = sf::Vector2f(x, y);
```

into mutex along with varray.append(vertex); and it works like intended